# .htaccess url rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

can anybody please tell me the rewrite rule so I can make a URL like this:

From:

```
http://www.mysite.com/info/?file=someinfo.nfo
```

Into:

```
http://www.mysite.com/info/someinfo.png
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^file=([^.]*)\.nfo$
RewriteRule info/ info/%1.png
```

(will fail if the filename contains a "." other than the one before the extension)

Comment: you could change it to `^file=(.+?)\.nfo$` which will capture dots as well.